# How we can synchronize HttpSession in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, el

My JSP contains javascript code,which include two function
One function is call a servlet

ie.window.showModalDialog("mams.openAndSave",...........)

for opening a report and setting a value in **HttpSession**.

And Another function use retrieve session value set previously using expression language

ie.dataToSave='${sessionScope.executionFilePath}';

but here **dataToSave** variable have not been initialized during form submission.
Above functions are called dynamically using link provided in JSP.

Any one know solution to this query,please reply

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to control the flow of your Javascript call. You can read about `<body onload="myFunction()">` and `document.ready` features to control the javascript function calls.You cannot directly access session objects using client side javascript directly. The session objects can be accessed with the help of ajax call to a servlet or any server side programs. Thus, the servlet access the HttpSession, sets the attribute value, gets the attribute value and return it to the client. HttpSession is not threadsafe by default. so, you can make it thread safe by locking the session object in the servlet or server side program as below

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
synchronized(session)
{
//setAttributes in the session object
//getAttributes from the session object
}
```

Hope this helps